# Change ModernCV section style to make them look like Friggeri CV

Tags: color, moderncv, friggeri-cv

I am using for my Resume the ModernCV template, but I would like to bring in some of the amazing FriggeriCV style of the title of the sections: I love the text half coloured and half black with each section styled by a different colour.
There is any way I can edit my template for that?  The image below is how the FriggeriCV looks like, and I would bring the heading styles.
[image: The image below]

Comment: From http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv you can download a `zip` file with all files needed to type a `Friggeri` CV. Bicolor sections are provided by default.

Comment: Thank you @Ignasi but I was looking for a way to personalize a bit ModernCV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having the bicolor section title is quite simple, using:

```
\section{\textcolor{magenta}{edu}\textcolor{black}{cation}}
```

or

```
\section{\bfseries \textcolor{orange}{exp}\textcolor{black}{erience}}
```

at every section start (I like the bold one more).

[image]

---

### EDIT

An automated way could be:

```
[...your preamble...]
\usepackage{xstring}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareRobustCommand\bcolor[2][color1]{%
{\bfseries\textcolor{#1}{\StrLeft{#2}{3}}% the number '3' stands for three letters
\textcolor{black}{\StrGobbleLeft{#2}{3}}
}}
```

and in the document you have three choices:

```
\section{Education}%standard section
\section{\bcolor{Experience}}%bicolor section with standard color
\section{\bcolor[orange]{Applications}}%bicolor section with custom color
```

[image: example]

Please note that the second part of the word is always set to be black in this example.

---

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{oldstyle}       
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\firstname{My}
\familyname{Name}
\address{my street}{my city}{my country}
%
\usepackage{lipsum,blindtext,xstring}
\DeclareRobustCommand\bcolor[2][color1]{%
    {\bfseries\textcolor{#1}{\StrLeft{#2}{3}}%
    \textcolor{black}{\StrGobbleLeft{#2}{3}}
    }}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{education} %standard section
\section{\bcolor{experience}} %bicolor section with standard color
\section{\bcolor[orange]{applications}} %bicolor section with custom color
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's almost what I was looking for. There is a way to make this automatic? Grazie :)

Comment: I edited the answer, try now! :)